# How can I get the entity ID after saving it?

Tags: 8, entities

I am saving an entity and I would want to get its ID.

```php
$CustomerEntity = CustomerEntity::create([
  'customer_id' => $customer['id'],
  'customer_name' => $customer['name'],
  'address' => $customer['address'],
]);

$CustomerEntity->save();
```

How do I get the entity ID with that code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `$CustomerEntity->id();` after saving your entity.

```php
$CustomerEntity = CustomerEntity::create([
  'customer_id' => $customer['id'],
  'customer_name' => $customer['name'],
  'address' => $customer['address'],
]);

$CustomerEntity->save();
$id = $CustomerEntity->id();
```

Comment: This apparently is empty if trying to get it one line below... when halting using a debug breakpoint and then reading it, it is perfectly filled.

Comment: Just to confirm Florians comment. If you add $entity-save() right after you have created it, then the $entity->id value becomes available. Strange but true.